# creating multiple files from reading data from a file

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I have written a c++ code to read from a file and create multiple files from there and write data into them. My input file is as follows:

```
11 2 3
22 3 14
33 4 15
```

the first digit of each line will be a file name and the following two digits are the data to be written into them. My code is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    ofstream os1;
    FILE *fp;
    int a;
    int k1,k2;
    char fileName[] = "0.txt";
    fp=fopen("input.txt", "r");

    while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &a) != EOF)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &k1);
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &k2);
        fileName[0]=a;
        os1.open (fileName);
        os1<<k1<<"\t"<<k2<<"\n";
        os1.close();
    }

}
```

But when I run the program, no file is created. Is there anything wrong in the code? how will I create the files?

Comment: Why are you using `fopen`, `fscanf` etc?

Comment: C++ has strict scope rules, to help you. Don't fight them. Define symbols where you need them, an no sooner. That'll solve several classes of errors with your code.

Answer (score 2):

When you read your "filename" with `fscanf(fp, "%d", &a);` the variable `a` will not contain an ascci value of '1' but an integer of binary value 1.

When you then set the first char of your filename with `fileName[0]=a;` the character will be '\x01` so a non printable character.  This is [prohibited in many filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations), which will probably cause your opening to fail.

So, always check the state of the file to see if open succeeds.

---

By the way,  why not use an `ifstream` for reading the file ?

```
int k1,k2;
string fileName = "0.txt";  
ifstream ifs("input.txt");

if (!ifs) {
    cerr << "Couldn't open input file" <<endl; 
    return 1; 
}

while (ifs >> fileName[0]) {    // note that you read a char, now 
    ifs >> k1 >> k2;
    ofstream os1(fileName);
    if (! os1) 
        cerr <<"Couldn't open output file "<<fileName<<endl; 
    else {
        os1<<k1<<"\t"<<k2<<"\n";
    } // closing is done automatically as os1 goes out of scope
 }
```

---

**Edit**

Well, your original code suggested that you expected one single digit to be read to construct the filename, so I just transposed in my answer to something equivalent.

So if you want to read a string as first element, it's relatively easily done:  instead of reading directly into `fileName[0]`, do:

```
string fileName; 
string fileSuffix = ".txt";   // only
... 
while (ifs >> fileName) {  // read a string 
    fileName += fileSuffix; 
...
```

The advantage is that you can now come with anything as input, such as:

```
11 2 3
E2 3 14
primes 7 11
```

If you want to read an integer you could very well do that

```
int a; 
string fileName; 
string fileSuffix = ".txt";   
... 
while (ifs >> a) {            // for people loving integers 
    fileName = to_string(a) + fileSuffix; 
...
```

Comment: so, how will I prevent this? what is the solution if I want to store 1? @Christophe

Comment: @AAA see my edit:  the easiest would be to read from a stream and then read a char instead of an int.

Comment: getting an error saying: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(const char [10], const char [2])'| @Christophe

Comment: @AAA sorry my mistake I've forgotten to remove "r" in the ifs constructor

Comment: now getting error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::basic_ofstream(std::string&)' @Christophe

Comment: @AAA have you included `<string>`  and do you compile for c++11 ?

Comment: if i want to store the first digit of each line into an int variable, then will the line (say: int a=fileName[0]) work? @Christophe

Comment: your code does not work for the edited input i have made in the post @Christophe

Comment: in the statement while (ifs >> a), what is the final value of a that breaks the loop? @Christophe